# Iphone: Scaling images down for smaller iphone3 and iphone4

Tags: resize, image-quality, ios, iphone

I am completing some design work on my application. Following a few people saying it is best to design for the iphone5 (4inch) screen first I have completed a page design for the retina. The image has then been sliced (cut up) as required for the iphone.

In terms of scaling down for the iphone3/4, is it best just to load the image in photoshop and  use Edit > Image Size... to bring the size down, or create a new image the correct size and scale all the layers down using Ctrl + T and shift to transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of doing what you are asking depending on the purpose you are following.

1. If your purpose is that the image has to scale automatically
   depending on the resolution of the device's screen where it is
   visualized then the prior answer by DA01 works fine. The scale job
   is done by using HTML5 and CSS. This is true if you are building a
   Web App, since Web apps permit the use of HTML5.
2. If you are building a native application then you have to do things
   in the most precise way using the best practices. In this case the
   images have to fit perfectly in the screen resolution and the best
   practice using Photoshop is to re-adapt the images editing their
   size (so with the edit > image size method) or in some cases
   rebuilding the image itself. Never use the Ctrl+t method because in
   most cases it could not be so precise. This method could be useful for
   a quick image scale, pondered upon visual needs, editing the image
   with image size instead could permit you to have more control also
   on different layers makin up the image itself.

Comment: Thank you the second option is the answer. In my case Image Size should work fine, checking the box Scale Styles

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the app with HTML5 you don't really need to scale down the images. The CSS will do that for you.

Comment: Its native 12345